# problem with handling JSON Format response

Tags: javascript, php, html

my problem is that I can't get an output on a website from an answer in JSON Format.

I have a php file (**Index**) where I send a request and I also get an answer in JSON Format and from my JavaScript File where I have used the appendChild method to get an output in my Index File but the output isn't showing.

```
function reqListener() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
    var response = JSON.parse(this.response);
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    main.innerHTML = '';
    response.forEach(todo => {
        main.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));

        main.appendChild(document.createTextNode("id: "));
        main.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo.id));
        main.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

        main.appendChild(document.createTextNode("titel: "));
        main.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo.titel));
        main.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

        main.appendChild(document.createTextNode("details: "));
        main.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo.details));
        main.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

        main.appendChild(document.createTextNode("time: "));
        var date = new Date(todo.time);
        var options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };

        main.appendChild(document.createTextNode(date.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options)));
        main.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

        main.appendChild(document.createTextNode("status: "));
        main.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todo.status));
    });
}

function loadTodos() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/js/loadtodo.php");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xhr.send();
}
```

As result I want the answer (JSON Format) showing as an output in my index file

Comment: You can't have a newline in `'2-digit'`. If that's not how the original code looks, please edit the question.

Comment: Does anything come back from that console?

Comment: The only answer to the request is the content of the database in Json format and the function reqListener from the JS file. But I have no real output. I see the answer only in the debugger of Firefox.

Comment: @Dmitriy if I'm not mistaken if I get nothing back the debugger should also receive no answer or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `JSON.parse()`

```
function reqListener() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
    var response = JSON.parse(this.response);
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    main.innerHTML = '';
    response.forEach(todo => {
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick answer. I've implemented your improvement but I still don't get an output

Comment: Can you add a sample of the JSON to the question? Maybe it's not an array. You can use jsonlint.com to format it nicely.

Comment: ```php [{
 "id": 1,
 "titel": "tst",
 "time": "2019-06-04",
 "details": "test"
}]

Comment: Does it really have `php` at the beginning? that's not valid JSON.

Comment: no im to stupid to format it correctly otherwise ^^

Comment: Check for errors in the JavaScript console. I have to leave now, sorry.